# Should I try to befriend evolutions in Pokemon Sleep?

Tags: pokemon-sleep

Every morning I have a couple of Pokémon I could befriend, and sometimes an evolution. I've seen a Flaaffy and a Haunter for example. However, they cost much more friendship points to befriend, but I've seen that evolving a Pokemon cost quite a lot of candy which seem to be quite scarce and only obtainable after a sleep. Considering that the evolutions seem quite rare, and therefor I think you need them befriend them directly (with either a master cookie or hope it gets a critical feed), is it worth spending resources on it? Do they find more berries/ingredients?

Comment: Most of the numerical data to calculate the benefits can be found in game, except for the random factors.  Hence, the benefits, either way, will likely depend on your goals and playing style.  Although, I don't see any competitive goal relative to other players.  Maybe you can narrow the question's scope.

Comment: @Jerry Good point about being the question quite broad. I am struggling still a bit where I should aim on with the abilities on my team, so I am not sure yet. Other websites are quite vague in their reasoning regarding rankings, so I have no clue myself if I should focus on berries or ingredients or whatever. Maybe I was subconsciously asking for a better strategy in general :)